# Interpret new line character using Hex code

Tags: java, hex, byte

I get row seperator value in one JSON and I use that as a parameter in my code.

Problem, When ever the JSON gets populated(By taking data from Database) having row separator as key and value `"\n"`, the output JSON comes with row separator value `"\\n"`.

I dont want to fix this (Becasue I dont want to), but is there any way I could replace my row separator value with hex of `"\n"`  in database, so that the moment my JSON populates, it shows the hex of `"\n"`.

So I'm curious to know, If I get hex(`5c6e`) of `"\n"` in JSON as value of row separator key, I could interpret in java and use it as a `"\n"` in my code ....?

Please share your ideas....!

Comment: Please share some code to see what are you trying to do and what frameworks are you using. Give a example with input and output.

Comment: If your row separator is a literal backslash followed by a literal `n`, Then `\\n` is the right value in the JSON. Why do you want to replace this with hex? What do you want to do with the hex?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, MauroAlmeida, Just want to know whether it can be done in java that using hex as row separator....? Becasue other Issues I can fix in code, that's not an issue...!